# Install 3rd party livechat script into our Magento store

Tags: javascript, integrate

We want to install a live chat tool onto our Magento store.
The tool is from LiveChatInc.com and requires you to add their javascript snippet before the closing  tag of the site.

Is this as simple as adding the code snippet to: `System > Configuration > Design > HTML Head > Miscellaneous Scripts` ?

There code snippet is JavaScript

Answer (score 3):

This will probably work **but** it adds the script within the `<head>` element instead of at the end of the `<body>` element, which hurts the user experience because it blocks page rendering until the script has loaded.

The right way™ would be to add it to the bottom via layout XML. Add the following lines to the `layout/local.xml` file of your theme:

```
<default>
    <reference name="before_body_end">
        <block type="core/text" name="live_chat_js" after="-">
            <action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[

... ADD YOUR SNIPPET HERE ...

]]></text></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to add a small amount of javascript you can just use the Miscellaneous Scripts box, being sure enclose your JS in  if it isn't already.

Alternatively you could add this to the head.phtml file in your theme or if it needs to be loaded after all other content the footer.phtml.

Comment: When you say enclosed, what do you mean? p.s. this is their code snippet: <script type="text/javascript">
var __lc = {};
__lc.license = 1111111;

(function() {
 var lc = document.createElement('script'); lc.type = 'text/javascript'; lc.async = true;
 lc.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'cdn.livechatinc.com/tracking.js';
 var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(lc, s);
})();
</script>

Comment: That's fine as is. By enclosed I meant that javascript needs to have the <script> tags around it in the header. The snippet there already does so you can just insert it straight in.